# How to change tomcat compiler

Tags: tomcat, java-7

I'm trying to use the new Java 7 switch on strings feature.

But Tomcat is not cooperating.

I've made sure that tomcat is running under java 7 but it seems that it's not compiling under it.

I've added the following to the web.xml file, under the jsp servlet entry

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compiler</param-name>
        <param-value>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac.exe</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are running Tomcat 6 and had the same problem. Our solution was to:

- replace `tomcat/lib/ecj-3.3.1.jar` with `ecj-3.7.2.jar` (can be taken from the latest Tomcat 7 release);
- add this to `tomcat/conf/web.xml`

  ```
  ...
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>                                    <!-- this should be added -->
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.7</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.7</param-value>
    </init-param>                                   <!-- last added line -->
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  ```

The simpler alternative is, of course, to install Tomcat 7 but this might not be an option for everyone.

Comment: Awesome.
In the end we were able to upgrade to Tomcat 7, but it certainly looks like your solution would have done the trick.

Comment: Also you can add this to your application's `web.inf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

We ran to the same problem, using jdk8 and tomcat6. Adding `compilerSourceVM` and `compilerTargetVM` with value of 1.8 to conf/web.xml will still not able to compile jsp when the code has switch with strings or lambda expression. However, replace ecj-4.3.1.jar from default lib come with tomcat 6.0.53 with ecj-4.6.1.jar (which can be found in maven repository), jsp will be able to compile successfully.

```
$ file ./work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/test1_jsp.class
./work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/test1_jsp.class: compiled Java class data, version 52.0 (Java 1.8)
```

Hope this help anyone who stuck with upgrading to jdk8 for tomcat6.

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing something here. You want your JSPs compile with Java 7 and not have the tomcat run with Java 7. Tomcat uses the Eclipse Java Compiler which is does not have Java 7 support yet.

Edit: I did some digging. As you can see [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper/7.0.14/org/apache/jasper/JspCompilationContext.java#216), the built-in Eclipse compiler is used. The compiler distributed with Tomcat 7.0.19 is ECJ 3.7 which will support Java 7 not before 3.7.1.

Comment: Michael-O. I'm trying to get *everything* to run / compile on Java 7.
I already have Tomcat running on 7, I'm just missing the capability to compile. That's why I'm looking for a way to move away form the default compiler.

Comment: You should rather contact the tomcat users mailinglist. Mark Thomas is really active on that one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tomcat version used, the JSP engine provided by tomcat uses a specific default version of Java to compile and run JSP.

**[Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)** uses the 1.6 version

> compilerSourceVM - What JDK version are the source files compatible
>   with? (Default value: 1.6)
>
> compilerTargetVM - What JDK version are the generated files compatible
>   with? (Default value: 1.6)

**[Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)** uses the 1.7 version

> compilerSourceVM - What JDK version are the source files compatible
>   with? (Default value: 1.7)
>
> compilerTargetVM - What JDK version are the generated files compatible
>   with? (Default value: 1.7)

**[Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)** uses the 1.8 version

> compilerSourceVM - What JDK version are the source files compatible
>   with? (Default value: 1.8)
>
> compilerTargetVM - What JDK version are the generated files compatible
>   with? (Default value: 1.8)

Of course, you may change the versions used if the default values don't match to your requirements.

You can do that by modifying the init parameters of the 
`org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` servlet declared 
in your global `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`.

For example the `web.xml` of the tomcat 8 distribution defined the JspServlet in this way :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
```

For example to specify the `1.8` version both as source and target for JSP files, you should change it in this way :

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>  
     <!-- added params -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
      <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
      <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <!-- end added params -->
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting [compilerSourceVM](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html) to 1.7 or 7 ? (I'm afraid I cann't claim to know if this works or not)

Comment: Joel, thanks for the reply, but it didn't work :( 
I set both compilerSourceVM and compilerTargetVM, tried with 1.7 and 7 and got the same result