# Diamond operator(<>) not working in java 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, javac

I have the following error for compiling a jsp file:

> '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

I'm using `jdk 1.7.x` and eclipse Kepler
Also I have set `1.7 as compliance level` in project preferences in Eclipse, still the code is not working

Should I add any other config?

Comment: Is 1.7 set as your Runtime Environment?

Comment: And that isn't called the "list operator". It's more like "inferred generic types".

Comment: Obviously you have NOT set the compiler/enviroment to 1.7.

Comment: May I know where it should be set?

Comment: right click on your project, Properties -> Java Build Path. What is there?

Comment: You can check also looking at package explorer  -`JRE System Library` version.

Comment: Strictly, it's called the Diamond operator and is not only applicable to lists.

Answer (score 9):

Check the following areas within Eclipse:

1. `Right Click Project > Properties > Project Facets > Java > Version 1.7`
2. `Right Click Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > JRE Library should be 1.7`
3. `Right Click Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level`
4. `Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Select the Server > Edit > Ensure JRE is set to 1.7`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but it still isn't working.. All the above mentioned properties are set to 1.7.0_25

Comment: Just to shed some light on things, if you place the code inside a class as opposed to the JSP does it complain?

Comment: Also make sure that you are pointing to the right JDK.  `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`.  Just ensure that it is pointing to the folder with 1.7 installed.

Comment: Working fine with a simple class.. Problem persists with JSP files though

Comment: I think the application server is running on a previous version of the JRE/JDK.  Do you have an older version set on your classpath or specified for java home?

Answer (score 0):

So the only way it seems now is that your application server, eg tomcat is configured for jdk version lower than 1.7. check what version of java is being pointed by JAVA_HOME environment variable on your system.If you correct that, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over 2 years since this thread was last active but in case someone is looking for an answer and the above checks don't solve it: it's because the compiler that your tomcat is running is older than 1.7. One way to solve this is to add this to tomcat/conf/web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>fork</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>                                    <!-- this should be added -->
      <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
      <param-value>1.7</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
      <param-value>1.7</param-value>
  </init-param>                                   <!-- last added line -->
  <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780639/how-to-change-tomcat-compiler/11810014#11810014)

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks