# Inspecting a bean in my JBOSS JMX Agent View fails with an error

Tags: java, jboss, dcm4che

I cannot inspect any of my beans in the JMX Agent View as clicking on any bean results in the error pasted below.
Every thing else seems to be working fine within JBOSS as it is properly serving my application.

Environment variables as follows...

PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

```
JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - Error report HTTP Status 500 - type Exception reportmessage description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 151 in the jsp file: /inspectMBean.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
148:             else if (String.valueOf(attrValue).indexOf(sep) == -1)
149:             {
150: %>
151:             <input type="text" name="<%= attrName %>" value="<%= attrValue.replace("\"","&quot;") %>" <%= readonly %>>
152: <%
153:             }
154:             else

An error occurred at line: 151 in the jsp file: /inspectMBean.jsp
The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
148:             else if (String.valueOf(attrValue).indexOf(sep) == -1)
149:             {
150: %>
151:             <input type="text" name="<%= attrName %>" value="<%= attrValue.replace("\"","&quot;") %>" <%= readonly %>>
152: <%
153:             }
154:             else

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:415)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.inspectMBean(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:220)
    org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.processRequest(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:96)
    org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.doGet(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:77)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA logs.JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked in jboss-4.2.3.GA:
In file

```
/server/{xxx}/deploy/jmx-console.war/inspectMBean.jsp
```

replace the affected

```
replace("\"","&quot;")
```

with

```
replaceAll("\"","&quot;")
```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works but I only tested it for jboss-4.2.3GA as well using JDK 1.8. Don't know whether it works for other versions of JBoss. It's important to mention here that all occurrences of the `replace` function need to be replaced by `replaceAll` (lines 21 and 22 in my version of the file).

Comment: Thanks. Best Solution especially when you are upgrading JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same thing happening.

Turns out I was missing **inspectMbean_jsp.class** in the **dcm4chee-2.17.2-psql\server\default\work\jboss.web\localhost\jmx-console\org\apache\jsp** folder.

Not sure why it isn't there

Comment: Will check this out in a few hours. Thank you for the response as this question had previously earned me a tumbleweed merit badge.

Comment: what version of java are you using? I was using 1.8 and it wasn't working but 1.7 works fine

Comment: I think I may be using 1.8 but I need to confirm as I have multiple versions loaded.

Comment: Same issue using Java 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 1):

I think more graceful solution would be to ensure that both `compilerSourceVM` and `compilerTargetVM` are set to `1.5` or above in `jboss/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml` as in [How to change tomcat compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780639/how-to-change-tomcat-compiler).

Also JDK 1.5 or above should be present and visible instead of default JDK 1.4 which doesn't understand [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method with string params.