# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tomcat issue in docker

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am tring to run tomcat 7.0.72 version in a docker container and I am running into the below issue:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I am using Java Version 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

According to some posts i'm seeing on google, it could be you're compiling the code for your servlets or whatever on java 7, but running on java 8

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700824/jdk-8-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643933/the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved-tomcat6-jdk7)

Comment: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode)
[root@5866b3f83000 lib]# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_111   --> it is 1.8 for the java compiler